# foreach não roda por completo, roda apenas 1 vez

Tags: php, html, foreach, template

boa tarde,
alguem tem alguma ideia do porque este **foreach** **não roda as 3 vezes**, e roda **apenas 1**?

**$pag = 3;**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
  {foreach from=$pag item=pg}
     <div class="fotos-flex active">      
        {foreach from=$photos item=p}
           <div class="fotos-item">
              <img src="img/galeria/1-EXCHANGEDEVELOPMENTPROGRAM- 
               GROUP-  
               2016.JPG">
              <p>Exchange Development Program Group - 2016</p>
          </div>
        {/foreach}
     </div>
  {/foreach}
```

Comment: E por que rodaria três vezes?

Comment: from=$pag, onde $pag = 3.

Comment: coloque o código imagem atrapalham o entendimento. parece que o seu for começo com o valor de 3, não é isso?

Comment: o valor inicial é 0 e deve ir até o 3.
assim como o outro foreach onde $photos = 13, porem ele roda normalmente as 13 vezes.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic codigo adicionado na pergunta.

Comment: O valor de `from` não deveria ser um objeto iterável? Parece-me que não faz sentido passar um número (mas nunca usei o Smarty)

Comment: https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/pt_BR/language.function.foreach.tpl eu estava lendo aqui ... se já viu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O laço ['foreach'](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/pt_BR/language.function.foreach.tpl) não é utilizado para iterar sobre um escalar. O `foreach` é usado para pegar cada elemento de uma matriz associativa simples.

Para iterar sobre escalares use o laço simples [`for`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.for.tpl):

```
  {for $pg=1 to $pag}
     <div class="fotos-flex active">      
        {foreach from=$photos item=p}
           <div class="fotos-item">
              <img src="img/galeria/1-EXCHANGEDEVELOPMENTPROGRAM- 
               GROUP-  
               2016.JPG">
              <p>Exchange Development Program Group - 2016</p>
          </div>
        {/foreach}
     </div>
  {/for}
```